# Ray Box intersection

Tags: graphics, 3d, geometry, intersection, raytracing

I was wondering if anyone knew of a good resource for ray-box intersection algorithms. I am writing a ray-tracing program and want to include a box-primitive object. To be specific, I need an algorithm that can return a "t value" for a ray parameterized as R = E + t*D where E is the starting point and D is the direction vector. I have already implemented a ray-box intersection that is useful for bounding boxes, but it only returns a boolean value for whether or not the box was hit. This is no good however since I need to be able to calculate the exact point in 3D space that the box was hit in order to be able to render it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are interested only in axes aligned boxes. The code is available in LuxRays sources: https://bitbucket.org/luxrender/luxrays/src/ceb10f7963250be95af709f98633907c13da7830/src/luxrays/core/geometry/bbox.cpp?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#bbox.cpp-148

Comment: Thanks -- do you know why though in the intersectionP routine they have two floats hitt0 and hitt1 that they update? Why not simply return the closest value?

Comment: hitt0 is always the closest value (i.e. the entering point of the ray) and hitt1 is always the farther point (i.e. the exist point of the ray). You can just pass a NULL in place of hitt1 if you don't need that value.

Comment: Oh okay I see. What happens though if the origin of the ray is from inside the box? Would the "near" value be null? Or does the algorithm treat the ray as being infinitely long and thus both values are always calculated?

Comment: @user1855952 It appears that `*hitt0` will be negative in that case.  If `*hitt1` is also negative, then the box is entirely behind the ray origin, otherwise the origin is inside the box.  For help understanding the algorithm see [here](http://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/raytrace/rtinter3.htm) and/or [here](http://tavianator.com/2011/05/fast-branchless-raybounding-box-intersections/).